# Setup ng.IModule controller in other files

Tags: javascript, angularjs, typescript

I have the following JavaScript that I'd like converted to TypeScript but I'm striking out :(

**JS**

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);
app.config([...]);
app.run([...];

(function (ng, app) {
  app.controller('appCtrl', [..., function(...)])
})(angular, app);
```

This is what I've got so far.

**TS**

File1:

```
/// <reference path="../Scripts/typings/angularjs/angular.d.ts" />
module App {
    "use strict";
    var mod:ng.IModule = angular.module(name, []);
}
```

File2:

```
/// <reference path="../Scripts/typings/angularjs/angular.d.ts" />
module App {
    'use strict';
    export interface IAppCtrlScope extends ng.IScope {
        greeting: string;
        changeName(name): void;
    }
    export class AppCtrl {
        public static $inject = [
            '$scope'
        ];
        constructor(private $scope: IAppCtrlScope) {
            $scope.greeting = 'asdf';
            $scope.changeName = (name) => {
                $scope.greeting = 'Hello ' + name + ' !';
            }
        }
    }
    mod.controller('appCtrl', AppCtrl); // this doesn't work
}
```

The reason behind doing `mod.controller('appCtrl', AppCtrl)` in the file where the controller is defined is because it's a lot easier to maintain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the solution was is really quite simple. All I had to do was to export the variable.

```
module Application {
    'use strict';
    export var angularApp: ng.IModule = angular.module("app", []);
}

module Application {
    'use strict';
    export interface IAppCtrlScope extends ng.IScope {
        greeting: string;
        changeName(name): void;
    }
    export class AppCtrl {
        public static $inject = [
            '$scope'
        ];
        constructor(private $scope: IAppCtrlScope) {
            $scope.greeting = 'asdf';
            $scope.changeName = (name) => {
                $scope.greeting = 'Hello ' + name + ' !';
            }
        }
    }
    angularApp.controller('appCtrl', AppCtrl)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use a class as a controller. Please see https://youtube.com/watch?v=WdtVn_8K17E&hd=1 for an example.

Comment: That's exactly what I'm doing

Comment: @Snæbjørn you are putting members *on the scope* e.g. changeName. You should just have them as members of the *class*

Comment: Fair enough but I haven't even gotten to that yet, that was just some copy paste code to see if something worked and it didn't.

Comment: `but I'm striking out` how exactly?

Comment: In JS I'd do this `(function (ng, app) { app.controller(...` nicely "scoped". I want to do the same in TS so I thought I'd use the module for this scoping. But I can't call `mod.controller(...` in the 2nd file and I can't do `angular.module('myApp', []).controller('appCtrl', AppCtrl);` in the 1st file because AppCtrl isn't defined yet. Also I really don't want to worry about execution order when I later have to bundle and minify.